# force:createRecord in standalone app without using salesforce1 app

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, salesforce1-platform

I want to build a standalone lightning app - without using salesofrce1.

Now the problem is I also need 'force:createRecord' way to create record for custom object with more than 10 page layouts, from my app.

Is there a way that I can avoid writing that number of views hardcoding fields?

Comment: How do you plan to connect to a Salesforce Instance?

Comment: @crmprogdev It's a lightning app so I'll be using Apex.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an Apex controller with JS remoting, I'd expect you to be able to pass the object name to the controller, then use a schema describe call inside of the Apex controller to obtain your field names for each object then pass them back to a Lightning App's js controller. In essence, you can do this using [Dynamic Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic.htm) inside your Apex controller.